# Can you download the compass/css3 file?

Tags: sass, dart

I can't get ruby running and i dont want to go through all the hurdles of fighting with my osx version of ruby.

I downloaded dart sass which has no support for compass since it's deprecated. I'm trying to get my old sass code to work while I work on replace all my mixin that I used that rely on compass.

Is there a way I can download the compass/css3 mixin stylesheet?

I found their site http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/ other than going through each page and copying all the code. Is there no master code file that I can download all the mixins?

Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/Igosuki/compass-mixins here you go